# What are the voltage levels in 100 Base-TX Ethernet?

Tags: voltage, ethernet, differential, level

I know what the differential voltage looks like. If you measure across Tx+ and Tx- it goes from -1V to 0V to 1V and so on, but how are these voltage levels actually transmitted?

Does Tx+ go from 0V - 1V and Tx- from -1V - 0V, or are both from 0V - 1V or something completely different?

Comment: ±2.5V across each twisted pair. But don't think of this like "2.5V for 1, -2.5V 0". Things are different. You can get any technical detail by searching "Ethernet Physical Layer".

Comment: Related: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/452881/what-does-ethernet-100base-t-signal-look-like/452882#452882

Comment: @RohatKılıç but that doesn't make too much sense to me since you can meaure the voltage across the pair and you get a range of +/- 1V, there cant be +/- 2.5 V...Do I miss something?

Comment: In your questiosn, you seem to misunderstand differential signaling: in differential signalling, you don't use the zero-volt difference as signal point! You use positive and *negative* voltages to signal.

Comment: "Do I miss something", yes, all of transmission line theory. Plus, you don't tell us *how* you measure an ethernet line in usage. The voltage levels without a device attached will not be the same as with a properly terminating one, AND network cards do have equalizers.

Comment: @MarcusMüller Okay so I have a device attached, so it is properly terminated and I am measuring from Tx+ to Tx-, so my signal looks exactly like the MLT-3 code (from -1V to 1V). 
What I dont get tho, when measuring the signal I get a difference of 1V at maximum, would't I measure a greater difference with 2.5V

Comment: @RohatKılıç 2.5V levels are used on 10BaseT, the question is about 100BaseTX which does use 1V levels.

Comment: @MarcusMüller 100BaseT uses MLT-3 line coding which does use 3 differential voltage levels, positive, zero, and negative.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the wire, as the interface is transformer isolated, there is no other voltage where to reference anything except for the two wires themselves that work as a pair. Thus at first it may not be even useful to discuss about voltages, but simply think about current instead : either no current flows, or it flows into one direction in the loop, or flows into the other direction in the loop.

If we do talk about voltages, for example we can take the average of both wires as the common voltage reference signal, such as the point of Ethernet transformer center tap, then if TX+ wire goes positive, the TX- will have an equal negative voltage, and vice versa, as the wires are a balanced and symmetrical differential pair, terminated into equal impedances.

That is how the wires work, but how it works on the chip side of the transformer is a completely different question, and depends on the chip, as there are multiple ways how the chip can drive the waveforms into Ethernet isolation transformer.

Comment: Thanks, that definetly helped!
If I were to drive the signal from a cable into a transformer, it would have a reference to ground again right? Would the voltage from Tx+ to Ground be 0.5V then?

Comment: If you connect Ethernet to isolation transformer, you can reference the transformer output to any voltage you want, including ground. If the transformer has 1:1 winding and has proper termination, it does not change the voltages in any way. If you measured -1 to +1 volts between two wires, that's 2Vpp, and you'll still measure -1 to +1 between two transformer output terminals, the same 2 Vpp.