# Ethernet 100 BASE-TX Question

Tags: voltage, current, ethernet, transceiver, phy

I'm using [this](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/KSZ9031RNX.pdf) Ethernet transceiver PHY to study the working of the RGMII interface.

I just want to understand 2 things.

## 1. What would be the output and input differential voltage levels on the pins 2,3 and 5,6?

If the PHY is to be operated on 100BASE-TX mode, then according to the table values on the electrical characteristics table on page 68, the output voltage (differential) will be only between 0.95V to 1.05V.

- Am I reading it correctly?
- In that case, what would be the receive differential voltage levels into the IC? That seems to be not given.

And according to this [accepted](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/452881/what-does-ethernet-100base-t-signal-look-like/452882#452882) answers, it is mentioned that 100BASE-T ethernet family has differential peak to peak voltage levels of 2V differential and 1V differential.

- Then, the above accepted answer would be in conflict with the datasheet values of 1.05V of differential input right?
  Can someone clarify?

## 2. Can someone explain the working of figure 18 on page 75?

- What is the purpose of D1 and D2 along with the RC?
- How does it work?

P.S.: I checked the wiki page of [Fast Ethernet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fast_Ethernet#Copper) to understand the voltage levels of 10BASE-T, 100BASE-T and 1000BASE-T families of ethernet, but I was not able to find anywhere.
If someone could please provide some document or article where I can see the MDI voltage levels of the above ethernet families, it would be helpful for my understanding.

Comment: you say you want to just understand 2 things, then ask 6 or 7 questions, depending on how you count!

Comment: @MarcusMüller, yes I agree. I couldn't know how else to ask my questions. I feel my follow-up questions are also related to the main questions.

Comment: If you see, some of those, are just confirming my doubts and understandings? Others are follow-up to the main question. I'm doing my homework of trying to understand from other sites and then only arriving here to ask my question.

Comment: If you are studying Ethernet, why not read the actual specifications, instead of reading random websites and datasheets of specific chips that implement Ethernet?

Comment: How to find the actual specifications and where will it be given?

Comment: @Newbie you can Google-search for a copy of IEEE 802.3, but it's written in an impenetrable way, but the information is there somewhere.

Comment: On the same data sheet (pg. 68) it specifies 1V peak differential output voltage. That is 2Vpk-pk differential. In agreement with the other source. .95 to 1.05 are just ranges.